# Bind 'this' on function with generic rest parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following function `bindF` has a type error:

```
type F<M, AS extends any[]> = (this: M, ...args: AS) => any;

function bindF<M, AS extends any[]>(f: F<M, AS>, m: M) {
    return f.bind(m); // error
}
```

```
Overload 1 of 6, '(this: F<M, AS>, thisArg: ThisParameterType<F<M, AS>>): OmitThisParameter<F<M, AS>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'M' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThisParameterType<F<M, AS>>'.
  Overload 2 of 6, '(this: (this: M, ...args: any[]) => any, thisArg: M, ...args: any[]): (...args: any[]) => any', gave the following error.
    The 'this' context of type 'F<M, AS>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: M, ...args: any[]) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'AS'.
          'any[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'AS', but 'AS' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
```

The problem seems to be that there isn't an overload of `bind` to handle the generic rest parameter `AS`. Is there a way to get around this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAWQDRQIIGUoQB7AgOwBMBnKAQ3xAG0BdAPigF4oAKYACwEtiAuKZKADphZAE4BzXmnQBKJgwogA3ACgVAMwCu+AMbBOAe3xQARpyLwBGLLgIlylWnRbq+llBjooAtnwRyAbxUoEKhRCGBNUWN1QTMiFm8ZVQBfIA)

Comment: `return f.bind(m as ThisParameterType<F<M, AS>>)` worked for me, kinda lazy but this is a scenario where casting values just saves many headaches...

Comment: The generic type should be the type of the function itself